# Sorting local collections in package

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'am trying to create a package that contains:
 - a simple query defined as a cursor
 - table type based on this cursor rowtype
 - pipelined function that returns this table type

```
create or replace package reports is 
  cursor cur(p_datebeg in integer, p_dateend in integer) is 
    /*select .. from .. where .. between p_datebeg and p_dateend*/
  type typ is table of cur%rowtype;
  function f_report(p_datebeg integer, p_dateend integer) return typ pipelined;
end reports;
```

Function fetches a cursor in local collection of package defined type and then pipeline it via loop.
It works fine. Then I add some actions on the data in collection, ruining initial sort order. Piping it still fine.
And then I'am trying to retrieve collection's sort order with subfunction. And that's a problem.

```
create or replace package body reports is
  function f_report(p_datebeg integer, p_dateend integer) return typ pipelined is    
    l_t typ := typ();
    function sort(p_t in typ) return typ is
      l_tt typ:= typ();  
    begin
      select * bulk collect into l_tt from table(p_t) order by 1;
      return l_tt;
    end;
  begin
    open cur(p_datebeg, p_dateend);
    fetch cur bulk collect into l_t;
    close cur;

    /*some actions with l_t*/
    l_t:= sort(l_t);

    for g in l_t.first..l_t.last loop
      if l_t.exists(g) then pipe row (l_t(g)); end if;
    end loop;
    return;
  end;
end reports;
```

Using it:

```
select * from table(reports.f_report(12378,12379));
```

Error pointing on line with attempt to access a p_t via table operator:

```
ORA-21700: object does not exist or is marked for delete
```

Main purpose of my task is to achieve a possibility to sort collection multiple times inside the function before outputting it.

UPD.
When trying to redeclare typ as a global type.

```
create or replace type t_typ as object
(reg varchar2(12),
 begday integer,
 mtcebase varchar2(6))
```

And use it in a header instead of cursors rowtype

```
type typ is table of t_typ;--cur%rowtype;
```

Encountering not enough values error on sorting bulk collect and type mismatch on fetch. It seems I just can not use it rightways. Anyway global type forces to mimic all initial query fields, that isn't quite good in case you use it as a pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`typ` must be defined as a SQL object type to be used in a `SELECT` statement.

```
create or replace type typ is object
(
    a number,
    ...
);
```

SQL and PL/SQL are run in completely different ways.  Normally Oracle passes data between them with minimum extra code.  But object types are *not* automatically translated, you need to manually create them first.

Yes, this is annoying.  Now you need a completely separate object that really belongs as a part of the package.  Your code makes sense, but it's an unimplemented feature.  (Although I think this limitation may be lifted in 12c?)

---

**UPDATE**

A pipelined function must return a nested table.  Here's a full example:

```
create or replace type t_typ as object
(
 reg varchar2(12),
 begday integer,
 mtcebase varchar2(6)
);

create or replace type nt_typ is table of t_typ;

create table test_table
(
 reg varchar2(12),
 begday integer,
 mtcebase varchar2(6)
);

insert into test_table values(30, 3, 'C');
insert into test_table values(20, 2, 'B');
insert into test_table values(10, 1, 'A');
commit;

create or replace package reports is 
  cursor cur(p_datebeg in integer, p_dateend in integer) is 
    select t_typ(reg, begday, mtcebase) from test_table where begday between p_datebeg and p_dateend;

  function f_report(p_datebeg integer, p_dateend integer) return nt_typ pipelined;
end reports;
/


create or replace package body reports is
  function f_report(p_datebeg integer, p_dateend integer) return nt_typ pipelined is    
    l_t nt_typ;
    function sort(p_t in nt_typ) return nt_typ is
      l_tt nt_typ;
    begin
      select t_typ(reg, begday, mtcebase) bulk collect into l_tt from table(p_t) order by reg;
      return l_tt;
    end;

  begin
    open cur(p_datebeg, p_dateend);
    fetch cur bulk collect into l_t;
    close cur;

    /*some actions with l_t*/
    l_t:= sort(l_t);

    for g in l_t.first..l_t.last loop
      if l_t.exists(g) then pipe row (l_t(g)); end if;
    end loop;
    return;
  end;
end reports;
/

select * from table(reports.f_report(0, 4));

REG   BEGDAY   MTCEBASE
---   ------   --------
10    1        A
20    2        B
30    3        C
```

Comment: Thanks! I've tried this earlier but unsuccessfully. Updated question.